# Add Mongo Index Via Javascript

Tags: python, mongodb, indexing

I want to add an index to my mongo collection outside of the interactive Mongo shell.

We're building in Python, so I could set it through MongoEngine, however, I'd greatly prefer to set the indexes directly.

Can I use db.eval() to make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `collection_name.create_index` API from Python.

http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.11/api/pymongo/collection.html

If using Javascript, the problem with `eval()` is that it needs a write lock, and creating an index itself needs a write lock. I do not think you can use `eval()` for anything that needs a write lock due to this reason.

Comment: Thanks Lobster.  You can create an index in the background, which I believe removes the need for a lock.  db.eval() failed for me, so I'm  game for your solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use [QuerySet.ensure_index](http://mongoengine.org/docs/v0.5/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.ensure_index).